# Use javascript to create a custom element that acts as sectioning content

Tags: javascript, dom, browser

Is it possible to use javascript to create a custom element that would be viewed by the browser outlining model as [sectioning content](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/content-models.html#sectioning-content)?

I have to currently wrap the insides of all custom elements that I want to do this with a `<section>` and it really would be nicer to just mark the element as sectioning directly.

Comment: You mean aside from [extending](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements) an existing one?

Comment: Good point @Sébastien I was thinking aside from extending cause I'm thinking of working this into an angularjs thing, but if thats the only approach then I might look into it.

Comment: I don't actually have any idea, but I'll be following your question ;)

Comment: After reading [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/sections.html#headings-and-sections) I would say that sectionning content is purely a notion based on the HTML spec, defining how User-Agents should behave, but which may have no related properties in the JavaScript API.